# "Failed to load libmysql.dll" with mysql server for ruby 2.2.1 rails 4.2.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I Successfully installed mysql2 0.3.18

I used this command to install the mysql2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir="C:\path of sql connector" -v'0.3.18'
```

But whenever I start the server using that gem, this is what i get:

```
 Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32\vendor
```

Comment: There are two separate things: the MySQL gem and the MySQL server. This looks like installation of the gem. Have you installed MySQL server? (I doubt you could find a MySQL server version that it wouldn't work on unless your system is really old...)

Comment: Before installing the mysql2 gem, you should have the mysql-server and mysql client libs installed.

Comment: i dont have mysql server yet sir because i dont know what version is compatible with this version of ruby. But i downloaded a mysql connector c  
6.1.5 x64

Comment: what version of mysql server should i install sir @ Santhosh?

Comment: This could be helpful for you: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#compatibility

Comment: Stil i got this error:

C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/my
sql2 (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

From the error, you are having trouble installing the mysql2 gem. I have installed MySQL on Windows (32-bit) via XAMPP a long time ago. Here is my version info:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for Win32 (ia32)

Once you have successfully installed MySQL and configured it properly, you will then be able to install the mysql2 gem. For me, bundle install always gets stuck on that gem, and I have to issue the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib="c:\xampp\mysql\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="c:\xampp\mysql\include" -v '0.3.17'
```

The paths here point to my installation of MySQL, and will not work for you unless you have already installed MySQL and in the same directory structure.

---

For your updated problem, it seems that your path was not updated when MySQL was installed. It needs to be able to find libmysql.dll- mine is here: C:\xampp\mysql\bin

Please add your equivalent directory to your path and accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you sir i based on your answer .... I successfully installed mysql2 but  i still got error when i start server

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. Although I had 64-bit MySQL installed and had 64-bit libmysql.dll it didn't work. I tried using 32-bit libmysql.dll and it worked perfectly.